# api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:17070: connection refuse

Tags: juju, maas, landscape

Fatal error and installation stop

```
ubuntu@ph1:~$ sudo grep -i error /var/log/juju/all-machines.log
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:48 INFO juju.api apiclient.go:339 error dialing "wss://localhost:17070/environment/69e65439-a3f7-44e5-830b-0a281a144a52/api": websocket.Dial wss://localhost:17070/environment/69e65439-a3f7-44e5-830b-0a281a144a52/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:17070: connection refused
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:48 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "api": unable to connect to "wss://localhost:17070/environment/69e65439-a3f7-44e5-830b-0a281a144a52/api"
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:51 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [1] user-admin@local 76.633us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:51 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [3] user-admin@local 53.154us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:52 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [5] user-admin@local 57.678us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:53 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [6] user-admin@local 59.389us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:54 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [7] user-admin@local 65.12us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:55 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [8] user-admin@local 59.742us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:56 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [9] user-admin@local 53.174us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:57 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [A] user-admin@local 51.944us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:58 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [B] user-admin@local 54.99us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:13:59 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [C] user-admin@local 55.611us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:00 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [D] user-admin@local 60.829us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:01 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [E] user-admin@local 57.954us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:02 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [F] user-admin@local 56.914us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:03 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [10] user-admin@local 59.018us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:04 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [11] user-admin@local 58.457us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:05 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [12] user-admin@local 58.452us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:06 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [13] user-admin@local 55.321us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:07 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [14] user-admin@local 61.989us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:08 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [15] user-admin@local 53.146us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:09 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [16] user-admin@local 56.042us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:10 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [17] user-admin@local 56.819us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:11 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [18] user-admin@local 58.405us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:12 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [19] user-admin@local 55.394us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:13 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [1A] user-admin@local 59.451us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:14 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [1B] user-admin@local 56.644us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:15 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [1C] user-admin@local 39.973us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:16 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:287 -> [2] machine-0 23.907428451s {"RequestId":9,"Error":"watcher has been stopped","ErrorCode":"stopped","Response":"'body redacted'"} NotifyWatcher["2"].Next
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:16 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:212 fatal "upgrader": must restart: an agent upgrade is available
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:16 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:212 fatal "api": must restart: an agent upgrade is available
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:16 INFO juju.worker.upgrader error.go:32 upgraded from 1.24.2-trusty-amd64 to 1.24.3-trusty-amd64 ("https://kwtuatopsph1.maas:17070/environment/69e65439-a3f7-44e5-830b-0a281a144a52/tools/1.24.3-trusty-amd64")
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:16 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:430 must restart: an agent upgrade is available
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:16 INFO juju.api apiclient.go:339 error dialing "wss://localhost:17070/environment/69e65439-a3f7-44e5-830b-0a281a144a52/api": websocket.Dial wss://localhost:17070/environment/69e65439-a3f7-44e5-830b-0a281a144a52/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:17070: connection refused
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:16 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "api": unable to connect to "wss://localhost:17070/environment/69e65439-a3f7-44e5-830b-0a281a144a52/api"
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:20 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:271 -> [2] user-admin@local 67.397us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:20 DEBUG juju.apiserver apiserver.go:271 -> [3] user-admin@local 56.45us {"RequestId":3,"Error":"upgrade in progress - Juju functionality is limited","Response":"'body redacted'"} Block[""].List
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:21 DEBUG juju.state open.go:283 closed state without error
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:212 fatal "instancepoller": cannot get instance data for machine 0: EOF
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "rsyslog": failed to write rsyslog certificates: cannot write settings: EOF
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "deployer": cannot get machine 0: EOF
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "0-container-watcher": cannot get machine 0: EOF
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "diskmanager": EOF
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "machiner": setting machine addresses: cannot set machine addresses of machine 0: EOF
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:223 exited "69e65439-a3f7-44e5-830b-0a281a144a52": cannot get instance data for machine 0: EOF
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.api.watcher watcher.go:84 error trying to stop watcher: connection is shut down
machine-0: message repeated 4 times: [2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.api.watcher watcher.go:84 error trying to stop watcher: connection is shut down]
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.rpc server.go:573 error writing response: write tcp 127.0.0.1:46416: broken pipe
machine-0: message repeated 3 times: [2015-08-10 14:14:21 ERROR juju.rpc server.go:573 error writing response: write tcp 127.0.0.1:46416: broken pipe]
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:15:14 ERROR juju.state.unit unit.go:739 unit landscape/0 cannot get assigned machine: unit "landscape/0" is not assigned to a machine
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:15:14 ERROR juju.state.unit unit.go:739 unit landscape/0 cannot get assigned machine: unit "landscape/0" is not assigned to a machine
machine-0: 2015-08-10 14:15:29 ERROR juju.state.unit unit.go:739 unit postgresql/0 cannot get assigned machine: unit "postgresql/0" is not assigned to a machine
```